# Can I implement a shared document link in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

I have documents on a shared network drive, which multiple people access and edit. I want to link to these documents from HTML (a Java web application), but most, if not all modern browsers, do not allow linking to local files.

I could implement these documents in a way where they are uploaded to the server, but if the users then requests these documents, they will receive a copy, and will have to upload them again for any changes to be visible to others.

I have more or less found confirmation that links to local (or in this case shared network) drives are not possible. Sharepoint have however found a way to implement what I want. But when I try to find out about their technical solution, I only find user guides to how to use the front end.

Are there any way to implement shared documents in a jsp web application, that does not require re-upload of documents?

I should say that the web application is an internal tool, and the shared network drive i mention has the same drive mapping on all users computers. It is not a must that the file remains on a shared network drive, but needs to work as if it is opened, and not downloaded as a copy, if at all possible.